# Angular 4 - event listener in directive not working

Tags: html, regex, angular

I've created a directive that prevents users from entering any characters except numbers, dot and comma. However, the event that should be called when user inputs something is not called and I don't understand why:

**input-validator.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appinputvalidator]'
})
export class InputValidatorDirective {

private regex: RegExp = new RegExp('^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$');

// Allow key codes for special events
// Backspace, tab, end, home
private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<td *ngIf="c.name == 'value' && typeId != 2">
<input class="form-control" 
       type="tel"  
       min="0" 
       step="1" 
       inputmode="tel" 
       appinputvalidator pattern="^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$"  
       pInputText 
       [(ngModel)]="item[grid.columns[y].dataKey]" 
       id="value1-{{i}}" 
       name="value1-{{i}}" 
       (keyup)="changeItem(item, $event, i)" 
       [required]="item.remark != null ? true : false" 
       [readonly]="typeID == 0 ? true : false" />
</td>
```

Even if I put debugger inside the onkeydown, it doesn't reach the code when I test it in browser. What's wrong?

I've imported it to app.module.ts like this

```
import { InputValidatorDirective } from './shared/components/inputvalidator.directive';
```

and also included it in @NgModule under "declarations":

```
    declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LeftMenuComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RightMenuComponent,
    ConfirmDialogComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    InputValidatorDirective
],
```

Stackblitz: [CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dejxs)

Comment: Seems to work when I test it in StackBlitz? (I've added a `console.log` statement). Can you create a StackBlitz to reproduce the issue please?

Comment: It's work for me also..

Comment: Maybe the issue is with `import`ing that directive into the module and placing that in `declarations` array!!!

Comment: I don't get the purpose of that, why not simply use a `input type="number"` ?

Comment: https://angular-xv2sn9.stackblitz.io

Comment: I've added it to app.module.ts like this "import { InputValidatorDirective } from './shared/components/input-validator.directive';
" and also included it in @NgModule under "declarations".

Comment: @BernardPolman - Please provide an editable version of stackblitz, not this one http://angular-xv2sn9.stackblitz.io

Comment: @AnkitSharma I am so sorry, I'm still new in this. I have edited my original post with new link, also here it is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dejxs

Comment: @BernardPolman - Could you please confirm if you have even created the directive file? I could not see any there.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't quite understand...I have created the directive file: http://prntscr.com/kne7ev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the image, your `input-validator.directive.ts` was outside the app folder.

I have edited and imported the directive in the app module.

Check the running [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pm4khm?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-validator.directive.ts) here. The app is now logging the `keydown` message.

Comment: Yes, it turns I imported it wrong. You gave me an idea to check other modules and it turns out I had to export it in shared.module.ts (which is another module where the whole component for the html was imported).